# CSS glyphicon position bottom not working

Tags: html, css, glyphicons

I have a simple question that I can't seem to figure out the answer to.  Why is bottom doing nothing in my example.  The parent position is set to relative, the child is absolute, the parent also has a height.  I can't seem to figure it out.  I know I can just use top, but I was curious as to why bottom doesn't work here.

```css
.profile-image-container {
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.profile-image-container .glyphicon {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 50px;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="profile-image-container">
  <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **bootstrap.min.css** has set the `top` property of the glyphicon class. So you need to set the `top` property to `auto` to override it.

```
.profile-image-container .glyphicon {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 50px;
  top: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to override your top property which is already defined in bootstrap.css.

```css
.profile-image-container {
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
 /* define your style more specifically */
 i.glyphicon {
  top: auto;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 50px;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="profile-image-container">
  <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i>
</div>
```